# Why is amount an integer in manage_offer operation?

Tags: payments, manageofferoperation

The [Manage Offer API doc](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer) states the `amount` is an integer.

Really??!?! In all the SDKs, the amounts are strings.

Is the doc here wrong?

Note: It's wrong in several places in that doc including other offer APIs and payments APIs

Answer (score 2):

This page documents the core API which takes integers. You must divide by 10^7 to get the actual numbers. All of the SDKs use strings which are the actual amounts.

So the doc isn't wrong, just a bit confusing to the reader.